# Brightness adjustment impossible after hibernation (MacbookAir 3.2, Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, brightness, hibernate, macbook-air

After waking my computer up from hibernation (close lid, open lid) I loose the ability to adjust the brightness with the F-keys and in the settings. It's the only problem I have with ubuntu on my macbook 3.2 :( Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue, but there is a workaround:

After waiting a minute or two, adjusting brightness works.